# repeat a process in Python

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I want to repeat asking number process while guess is not equal with TrueNum but when I put it in while loop it just repeats the print of its "if"
what should I do?

```
import random

# Defining True Num:
DataRange = list(range(0, 11))
TrueNum = int(random.choice(DataRange))
print("it`s in range from o to 10")

# Getting Guesses From User:
Guess = int(input("Input your number: "))

# Checking Guess:3
while Guess != TrueNum:
    if Guess > TrueNum:
        print("You Are Getting Far...")

    elif Guess < TrueNum:
        print("It`s bigger than you think :)")
    break

if Guess == TrueNum:
    print("yeah that`s it")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the input inside the while, and is good also to take out some unnecessary conditions:

```
import random

# Defining True Num:
DataRange = list(range(0, 11))
TrueNum = int(random.choice(DataRange))
print("it`s in range from o to 10")

# Getting Guesses From User:
Guess = int(input("Input your number: "))

# Checking Guess:3
while Guess != TrueNum:
    if Guess > TrueNum:
        print("You Are Getting Far...")
    else:
        print("It`s bigger than you think :)")
    Guess = int(input("Input your number: "))

print("yeah that`s it")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Try/Except allows you to address an invalid choice while also keeping readability.

```
import random

# Defining True Num:
DataRange = list(range(0, 11))
TrueNum = int(random.choice(DataRange))
print("it`s in range from o to 10")

# Getting Guesses From User:
while True:
    try:
        Guess = int(input("Input your number: "))
        if Guess > TrueNum:
            print("You Are Getting Far...")
        elif Guess < TrueNum:
            print("It`s bigger than you think :)")
        elif Guess == TrueNum:
            print("yeah that`s it")
            break

    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid Choice")
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable Guess is defined outside the loop, you should put the input  and check the value inside the loop.

```
import random

datarange = list(range(0, 11))
trueNum = int(random.choice(datarange))
print("Guess the number! It`s in range from o to 10")

while True:
    Guess = int(input("Input your number: "))
    if Guess == trueNum:
        print("Yeah that`s it")
        break
    elif Guess > trueNum:
        print("You Are Getting Far...")
    else:
        print("It`s bigger than you think :)")
```